# Django IntegrityError while deleting objects

Tags: mysql, django

I have 2 models, Post and Category:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # some fields

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='posts',
                                 on_delete=models.SET(get_default_category()))
```

`get_default_category` is basically just the shortcut for `get_or_create`.

When I try to delete some object (using .delete() or from the admin app), I get the following exception:

```
IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tatatata`.`discussions_post`, CONSTRAINT `category_id_refs_id_783afa2fc9c73207` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `discussions_category` (`id`))')
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing a callable instead of `get_default_category()`.

```
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='posts',
                                 on_delete=models.SET(get_default_category))
```